# trying to understand the assembly instruction: cltd on x86

Tags: assembly, x86, att

I found the assembly instruction

```
cltd
```

by disassembling code on an Intel architecture. The description I found was, that it clears the %edx register, but I don't understand what happens.... can anyone explain what the command exactly does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cltd` converts signed long to signed double long

If you want to see a diagram of what happens, jump to page 160 of http://download.intel.com/products/processor/manual/325462.pdf (more details on page 681)

Comment: Link is invalid now

Answer (score 29):

`cltd` is an alias for `cdq` ([reference](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dMnemonics.html)), which sign-extends `eax` into `edx:eax`.

What this means in practice is that `edx` is filled with the most significant bit of `eax` (the sign bit). For example, if `eax` is `0x7F000000` `edx` would become `0x00000000` after `cdq`. And if `eax` is `0x80000000` `edx` would become `0xFFFFFFFF`.

Comment: I found the description, but I still don't get it :/

Comment: As I say in my answer: `edx` is filled with the most significant bit of `eax` (the sign bit). I think that's about as clear as it gets.

Answer (score 1):

It looks pretty straightforward to me: [cltd converts the signed long in EAX to a signed double long in EDX:EAX by extending the most-significant bit (sign bit) of EAX into all bits of EDX."](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-3773/instructionset-49/index.html)

Comment: Ah, I got it. "sign-extend EAX -> EDX:EAX" thanks for the link ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Simpler than that, for example:

If the bit is less than `0x7F000000`, which is less than 127 in decimal, its "positive", is between 0 to 127.

If the bit is greater than `0x80000000` it's more than 128 in decimal, its "negative", is between -1 and -128.

So edx will get `0x00000000` for pos and `0xffffffff` for neg.

For example as a hack it can be used to null edx when you know eax is pos number instead of `xor rex, edx`.

P.S. `cltd` might not compile as `0x99` in some asm compilers. Better to use `cdq`

Answer (score 1):

Summary of [the documentation](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dMnemonics.html) that [was mentioned by Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17170478/895245):

```
Intel   AT&T   From   To
CBW     CBTW   AL     AX
CWDE    CWTL   AX     EAX
CWD     CWTD   AX     DX:AX
CDQ     CLTD   EAX    EDX:EAX
CDQE    CLTQ   EAX    RAX
CQO     CQTO   RAX    RDX:RAX
```

And now some commented code snippets:

```
/* Quad to Octo: top bit is zero: extend with zeroes. */
mov $0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, %rax
mov $0x123456789ABCDEF0, %rdx
cqto
mov %rax, %r12
mov %rdx, %r13
/* rax is unchanged. */
LKMC_ASSERT_EQ(%r12, $0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
/* rdx is filled with zeros. */
LKMC_ASSERT_EQ(%r13, $0)

/* Quad to Octo: top bit is one: extend with ones. */
mov $0x8000000000000000, %rax
mov $0x123456789ABCDEF0, %rdx
cqto
mov %rax, %r12
mov %rdx, %r13
LKMC_ASSERT_EQ(%r12, $0x8000000000000000)
LKMC_ASSERT_EQ(%r13, $0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)

/* Intel equivalent syntax also accepte by GNU GAS. */
mov $0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, %rax
mov $0x123456789ABCDEF0, %rdx
cqo
mov %rax, %r12
mov %rdx, %r13
LKMC_ASSERT_EQ(%r12, $0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
LKMC_ASSERT_EQ(%r13, $0)

/* Smaller size example: Double to Quad.
 * Also zeroes top 32-bits of RDX like many 32 to 64 operaions. */
mov $0xFFFFFFFF7FFFFFFF, %rax
mov $0x123456789ABCDEF0, %rdx
cltd
mov %rax, %r12
mov %rdx, %r13
LKMC_ASSERT_EQ(%r12, $0xFFFFFFFF7FFFFFFF)
LKMC_ASSERT_EQ(%r13, $0)

/* Even smaller size example: Word to Doubleword.
 * Unlike the 32-bit one, does not zero out the top 32-bits of RDX. */
mov $0xFFFFFFFFFFFF7FFF, %rax
mov $0x123456789ABCDEF0, %rdx
cwtd
mov %rax, %r12
mov %rdx, %r13
LKMC_ASSERT_EQ(%r12, $0xFFFFFFFFFFFF7FFF)
LKMC_ASSERT_EQ(%r13, $0x123456789ABC0000)
```

and

```
/* CLTQ: top bit is zero: extend with zeroes. */
mov $0x123456787FFFFFFF, %rax
cltq
LKMC_ASSERT_EQ(%rax, $0x000000007FFFFFFF)

/* CLTQ: top bit is one: extend with ones. */
mov $0x1234567880000000, %rax
cltq
LKMC_ASSERT_EQ(%rax, $0xFFFFFFFF80000000)

/* CWTL: zeroes top 32-bits. */
mov $0x123456789ABC8EF0, %rax
cwtl
LKMC_ASSERT_EQ(%rax, $0xFFFF8EF0)
CWTL

/* CBTW. */
mov $0x123456789ABCDE80, %rax
cbtw
LKMC_ASSERT_EQ(%rax, $0x123456789ABCFF80)
CWTL
```

Runnable GitHub upstreams:

- [CLTQ](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/564735fbfcc60f73703f141adfeb24bea9104442/userland/arch/x86_64/cltq.S)
- [CQTO](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/564735fbfcc60f73703f141adfeb24bea9104442/userland/arch/x86_64/cqto.S)

Comment: Related: my answer on [What does cltq do in assembly?](//stackoverflow.com/a/45386217) has a table of Intel/AT&T equivalences, and Intel / AMD translations of `cwde` and so on into `movsx` / `movswl` instructions and so on.

Comment: @PeterCordes ah, I completely forgot about that question! So many.